# How to disable selecting picture in Kid's Corner?

Tags: kids-corner

In Windows Phone 8 there is facility of activating child mode or guest mode and the mobile owner can limit what apps such users can access.

But there is problem and it is guest user can still set his pic from customize option and he will be able to see your pictures folder.

So it kills the whole idea of restricting access. So is there any way to disable that customization option in guest user mode or at least restrict access to photos folder? Thanks.

And I am using Nokia Lumia.

Comment: Never noticed this but indeed the child can browse all local photos. It even can roll photos in the camera too. I don't know any settings to do what you want.

Comment: You can disable it by voting here: http://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions/suggestions/5638561-disable-picture-access-from-kids-corner

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder I think you can form this in concrete answer (something like "...this behavior is by design......behaves the same on 8.1 dev......it already has its own feature request - link...")

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be by design. As Mikael suggested, vote for this idea - http://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions/suggestions/5638561-disable-picture-access-from-kids-corner